# multiple directives on a single element - how is scope resolved?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following html:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <span directive-isolate-scope ng-repeat="word in words">{{word.name}}<br></span>
    <span directive-new-child-scope ng-repeat="word in words">{{word.name}}<br></span>
</body>
```

And the following js:

```
angular.module('plunker', [])

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.words = [
      {name:'Ben'},
      {name:'Anna'}
    ]
})

.directive('directiveNewChildScope', function(){
  return {
    scope: true,
    link: function link(scope, element, attrs) {
      debugger;
    }
  }
})

.directive('directiveIsolateScope', function(){
  return {
    scope: {},
    link: function link(scope, element, attrs) {
      debugger;
    }
  }
});
```

[Here is](http://plnkr.co/edit/MAEFlb6k4VEzTUNmM5aO?p=preview) the Plunker example.

Here is the list of questions that I'd like to know answers to:

1. Is the `scope` that is passed to `link` function of
   `directiveIsolateScope` is an isolated scope created by the
   directive? If so, why does it have the scope created by `ng-repeat`
   directive as a parent?
2. Is the `scope` that is passed to `link` function of `directiveNewChildScope` is a child scope created by the directive? 
   scope inherited from the scope created by `ng-repeat`? I suppose
   that there is no transclusioning happening here.
3. When and where the scope that is passed to these directives is created?

Comment: directives have priorities.

Comment: can you drill down a bit regarding scope resolution question? What specific concerns do you have? Also need to understand that `ng-repeat` is of itself a directive, as are most `ng-` attributes